# AngularJS local storage service wrong return

Tags: angularjs, html, local-storage

I have this service in my app. Service to set and get user in localstorage. But the getUser function was returning the JSON.parse function not my object.

Anybody know how to resolve this insue?

The code is here:

```
 .service('UserService', function() {
  // For the purpose of this example I will store user data on ionic local storage but you should save it on a database
  var setUser = function(user_data) {
    window.localStorage.extract = JSON.stringify(user_data);
  };

  var getUser = function(){
      console.log(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.user || '{}'));
    return JSON.parse(window.localStorage.user || '{}');
  };

  var clearUser = function(){   
      delete window.localStorage.user;    
  };

  return {
    getUser: getUser,
    setUser: setUser,
    clearUser: clearUser
  };
})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use the localStorage.get/set item methods like below. So your service would look like

```
.service('UserService', function() {

  var getUser = function(){
    return JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('user'));
  };


  var setUser = function(user){
    JSON.stringify(window.localStorage.setItem('user', user));
  };

  return {
    getUser: getUser,
    setUser: setUser
  };
})
```

Comment: I had same result.
The object returned from getUser function ins't localstore item, but is the function JSON.parse prototype.